# How to write an absolute value expression in linear programming?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mathematical-modeling

My objective function for the Xpress-IVE (Mosel lang) model is

minimize |a-b|

where a and b the number of elements in the decision variables which are arrays.

Since there is no function to calculate the absolute value, i want to get something of the form

objective = max(a,b) - min(a,b)

and then minimize the objective

What I have tried:
introduced two variables x and y with the following constraints:
x >= a
x >= b
y => a
y => b
and re-written the objective as x-y

But this gives me zero as the solution.

Could I please get a hint on what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Minimizing 
$$
Z=|a-b|
$$
is equivalent to minimizing
$$
Z=\omega,
$$
subject to the constraints
$$
a-b\le \omega\\
b-a \le \omega
$$

Comment: Thanks. Do i define w as an integer?

Comment: No need to. If $a$ and $b$ are integers so will $\omega$.

Comment: Ok. But when i run it, i still get zero as the solution..

Comment: If you are just minimizing $|a-b|$, it is normal: the minimum value of an absolute value is 0. Do you have any other constraints?

Comment: Yes, they are as follows: a,b >= 0; fixed percentage constraints(decimals) for the decision variables U,V which are arrays of multiple variables. Even though, i've fixed U and V to be binary, on running the model, the resulting arrays contains decimals in some places instead of 0 or 1.

Comment: Related? http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~vandenbe/ee236a/lectures/pwl.pdf